# Not Advisable to use wait(),notify() methods in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am a beginner in multithreading and came across the following in OCJP7 edition:

> Avoid using methods such as Object.wait, Object.notify, and Object
>   .notifyAll in tasks (Runnable and Callable instances) that are
>   submitted to an Executor or ExecutorService.

Can someone please explain why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an `Executor` you do not know how tasks are scheduled on threads. Indeed, it is possible for there to be only a single thread.

In the pathological case you end up in a situation where you `Object.wait()` on a single threaded executor in a task... and there is nothing being run to `notify()` *because* it is a single threaded executor. As a result you have deadlock.

Even with more threads you can still end up in a similar deadlock situation if the relevant tasks happen to be scheduled on the same thread.

In any case, the blocking behaviour of `Object.wait()` means you are stalling a thread, whereas the whole idea of an executor is to farm out as many jobs as possible to a much more limited number of threads. What this means is that even at best you are reducing the throughput significantly by blocking an entire thread *and* all the other waiting tasks that were scheduled for it. I.e. you are not just blocking the task that does `wait()` you are also blocking any task scheduled behind it on the same thread since that task must wait to run until your blocking tasks is finished.

Comment: "there is nothing being run to notify()" - not necessary, there can be threads outside the thread pool, e.g. main thread which started a bunch of tasks and waits them to finish. There is nothing wrong in using Object.notify and Object.notifyAll in tasks.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov not in the pathological case, *that is precisely why* it is pathological... I am not saying you cannot ever use `wait()` or `notify()`, I am merely explaining why doing so in tasks that are being scheduled to an `Executor` *may* not be the brightest idea, hence the warning OP mentions.

Comment: you described pathological case as where Object.wait() is used. I am talking about Object.notify and Object.notifyAll only, not about Object.wait().